# Plex owns SSL cert correct?

Tags: encryption, tls

Plex's HTTPS certificate is great to have for the average MITM attack, however it is my understanding that the private key would still be controlled by Plex, correct? They are issuing the certificate, signed by Digisign, but installed by Plex. Therefore would a plex server not only be as secure as Plex's ability/willingness to retain the private key?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's that case with any SSL/TLS implementation.  The server needs the private key (in addition to the public key, which is usually contained in the certificate) to facilitate SSL/TLS, and the private key must be kept `private`.  If the server's private key is compromised, then an attacker can intercept and/or modify information sent between the client and the server.